# Quickest way to organize categorized data in a text file and convert to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a text file with hundreds of rows. Data fields and values separated by a colon and one empty line separating each data set. It looks something like this...

```
icon:rain
temperatureHigh:55.37
temperatureLow:42.55
humidity:0.97
windSpeed:6.7
precipType:rain
precipProbability:0.97

icon:partly-cloudy-day
temperatureHigh:34.75
temperatureLow:27.1
humidity:0.8
windSpeed:15.32
precipType:snow
precipProbability:0.29

icon:clear-day
temperatureHigh:47
temperatureLow:31.72
humidity:0.64
windSpeed:9.27
precipType:rain
precipProbability:0.01
```

I'm struggling trying to format this into a CSV with the desired output looking like this...

```
"icon","temperatureHigh","temperatureLow","humidity","windSpeed","precipType","precipProbability"
"rain","55.37","42.55","0.97","6.7","rain","0.97"
"partly-cloudy-day","34.75","27.1","0.8","15.32","snow","0.29"
"clear-day","47","31.72","0.64","9.27","rain","0.01"
...and so on, and so forth.
```

I've been trying to use `Get-Content` with replace, but would it be possible to use `Import-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv`?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Import-Csv .\file.txt -Header column1,column2,column3,colum4,column5 -Delimiter ':'

Comment: wasnt this question asked before?

Comment: @JohnnyCarino `Import-Csv` doesn't work with the input format the OP has.

Comment: This looks like the output of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935764/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-data-fields-returned-by-dark-sky-weather-api) Instead of saving the list formatted output, I'd pipe to `| Export-Csv .\your.csv -NoTypeInformation` eventually with the `-Append` parameter.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks for looking into it. Great advice, much simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regex` is the way to go:

```
$data = @'
icon:rain
temperatureHigh:55.37
temperatureLow:42.55
humidity:0.97
windSpeed:6.7
precipType:rain
precipProbability:0.97

icon:partly-cloudy-day
temperatureHigh:34.75
temperatureLow:27.1
humidity:0.8
windSpeed:15.32
precipType:snow
precipProbability:0.29

icon:clear-day
temperatureHigh:47
temperatureLow:31.72
humidity:0.64
windSpeed:9.27
precipType:rain
precipProbability:0.01

'@

$head = $data
$head = $head -replace '([^\s]+):([^\s]+)', '"$1",'
$head = $head -replace '\n\n', '::'
$head = $head -replace '\n', ''
$head = $head -replace '(.*?)::.*', '$1'
$head = $head -replace ',\s*$', ''
$head

$rows = $data
$rows = $rows -replace '([^\s]+):([^\s]+)', '"$2",'
$rows = $rows -replace '\n\n', '::'
$rows = $rows -replace '\n', ''
$rows = $rows + "::"
$rows = $rows -replace '::', "`n"
$rows = $rows -replace ',\s*\n', "`n"
$rows
```

Output:

```
"icon","temperatureHigh","temperatureLow","humidity","windSpeed","precipType","precipProbability"
"rain","55.37","42.55","0.97","6.7","rain","0.97"
"partly-cloudy-day","34.75","27.1","0.8","15.32","snow","0.29"
"clear-day","47","31.72","0.64","9.27","rain","0.01"
```

Comment: Thank you. The output was very close to what I am looking for. I edited my original post with the actual data. Hopefully that helps

Comment: @JohnnyCarino, if you find the answer useful, please rate it and mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$CurrentElement=[pscustomobject]@{}

#get all rows and add element list when row empty is founded
Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | %{

    if ($_ -eq "")
    {
        $CurrentElement
        $CurrentElement=[pscustomobject]@{}
    }
    else
    {
       $Row=$_.split(':')
       Add-Member -InputObject $CurrentElement -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Row[0] -Value $Row[1]
    }

}  | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -notype

$CurrentElement  | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -notype -Append
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to split your data at 2 consecutive newlines and convert the data chunks into hashtables via [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-3.0) (you must also replace `:` with `=` for that to work). The hashtables can then be converted to custom objects and exported to a CSV.

```
$data = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' -Raw

$data -replace ':', '=' -split '\r?\n\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]($_ | ConvertFrom-StringData)
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Note that the above requires PowerShell v3 or newer. For older PowerShell versions you need to adjust the code as below:

```
$data = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' | Out-String

$data -replace ':', '=' -split '\r?\n\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    $prop = $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $prop
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If you want the fields of the CSV in a particular order you can put a `Select-Object` between the `ForEach-Object` and `Export-Csv`:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
    ...
} | Select-Object icon, temperatureHigh, ... | Export-Csv ...
```

---

`Import-Csv` expects the input data organized as one dataset per row. It cannot be used for blocks of key:value pairs like your input data has.

`ConvertTo-Csv` requires the same preparation as `Export-Csv` in the sample code above. The only difference is that the output isn't written to a file.

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to do the job with a combo of simple regex patterns and string operators.

```
$InStuff = @'
column1:value1
column2:value2
column3:value3
column4:value4
column5:value5

column1:value6
column2:value7
column3:value8 
column4:value9
column5:value10

column1:value11 
column2:value12
column3:value13 
column4:value14
column5:value15
'@


$SplitInStuff = $InStuff -split ([environment]::NewLine * 2)

$HeaderLine = ($SplitInStuff[0] -replace '(?m):.+$').Split([environment]::NewLine) -join ', '

$CSV_Text = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$CSV_Text.Add($HeaderLine)

foreach ($SIS_Item in $SplitInStuff)
    {
    $CSV_Text.Add(($SIS_Item  -replace '(?m)^.+:').Split([environment]::NewLine).Where({$_}) -join ', ')
    }

$Results = $CSV_Text |
    ConvertFrom-Csv

# on screen
$Results |
    Format-Table

# to CSV
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\JohnnyCarino_ReformatedData.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

output ...

```
column1  column2 column3  column4 column5
-------  ------- -------  ------- -------
value1   value2  value3   value4  value5 
value6   value7  value8   value9  value10
value11  value12 value13  value14 value15
```

CSV file content ...

```
"column1","column2","column3","column4","column5"
"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"
"value6","value7","value8 ","value9","value10"
"value11 ","value12","value13 ","value14","value15"
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do what you want in simple, and hopefully clear code. I did not use sophisticated PS objects, methods or functions so it that it is clear and simple. The input is expected to be in a text file called in1.txt. I assume that each set of date has at most 7 lines (before a space or end-of-file is encountered). I did not make it generic or include error checking, etc. Needless to say, there are many other ways you can do this. If you have any comments let me know.

```
#======================
# Function used by code
#======================

Function func-PrintSet
{

 $s1=''
 $del= ','
 $q='"'
 foreach ($element in $arr1) {
     $s1=$s1+$q+$element+$q + $del 
 }
 $s1

 $s1=""
 foreach ($element in $arr2) {
     $s1=$s1+$q+$element+$q +  $del 
 }
 $s1

}

#=====================
# Main code
#=====================

# simple initialization of arrays.

$arr1=0,0,0,0,0,0,0
$arr2=0,0,0,0,0,0,0
$i=-1
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("in1.txt")
while ($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) 
{
    IF ($line)
    {

         $items = $line.split(':')
         $i=$i+1
         $arr1[$i]= $items[0]
         $arr2[$i]= $items[1]
    }
    ELSE
    {

        func-PrintSet   
        $i=-1
    }
}
func-PrintSet

"Done :)"

# Code end
```